# Workbench Trims long text updated into varchar column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I'm trying to paste a 2300 character English text into a 3000 character varchar column in **Workbench 6.1** into MySQL RDS database.

For some reason it only allows 258 character to be entered and it automatically trims the text and adds three points ('...') at the end.

I tried adding just a few characters after the 258 that already inserted and it does the same. I tried updating the field in 'Form Editor', but with no luck and same results.

What's the problem? - I've double checked that the column is 3000 varchar.I had no problem updating the field on local machine in PhpMyAdmin. I think that there is some type of limiter that does that, but couldn't find anything in the preferences.

Update: I tried right click and open and editor and save, the editor is opened, but the long text is not applied when I click the 'Apply' button.

Comment: Essential info missing: where do you paste the text (SQL IDE, modeling...)? There are several places where you can do that. Platform/OS? How did you check what is actually stored? The continuation ellipses are essentially only a visualization to indicated more text.

Comment: I did check it on a live website and using another client and it's truncated. I tried inserting it using Heidi client and it worked well